# random value is getting replaced in oracle procedure after compilation

Tags: plsql

I am running a code in a plsql package where I am using bind variable like this -

sql:= 'insert into test_table select * from '||dynamic_table||' where id = :bind1 and nvl(col1,:X)=:X';
execute immediate sql using vid,'Y','Y';

code is all compiled and running but whenever I am compiling and checking the body of my package the execute immediate get automaticlly replaced by some  random letter  'u' like below-

execute immediate sql using vid,'u','Y';
Why is this happening, there is no compilation issue but correct value is not getting inserted because of this random letter u.

Comment: What makes you think the `Y` is being replaced with a `u`? How have you identified that it's happening?

Comment: after compilation when I check the package body and tthe code changes .I can see'u' in place of 'Y'.And only 1 y out of 2 Y is getting replaced by u. This is so weird

Comment: Are you definitely checking the right package? I would be querying `dba_source`, filtering on the package name to confirm the contents of the package and to make sure you're looking at the right one. Could there be a DDL trigger that's somehow making the change, although that seems bizarre. Maybe the package is editioned and you're looking at an earlier version of it?

Comment: No its a fresh package made by me in development env and I am checking the correct one

Comment: If you create the package under a new name, does it still happen? What if you change the value to something other than Y or u? It could be that you've got some hidden characters in that part of the package that's causing it to go funny; you could try deleting the whole area of text and then retype it from scratch, and see if that helps.

Comment: yeah its too weird but its 5k lines code and I cant retype.Its happening when I compile the package and close the package.When I open its body again it gets replaced.

Comment: I don't mean type out the whole thing, just the text around the point that keeps changing. Maybe a few "words" either side of that point

Comment: A process I have needed a couple times. Save your package to a text file then load into an different editor that has show white space option and hex display option.  Then see if you have a stray unprintable character.